# Enable / Add a forum on mahara

Tags: forum, mahara

Im really new to mahara, and wondered how to enable the forum on mahara. Also if there is n't one out of the box, can anyone point me in the right direction for getting one please.

Its clearly something thats available as there is a community forum on the mahara website:

http://mahara.org/interaction/forum/index.php?group=1

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahara does ship with a forum. You can enable and configure it under Administrator Area -> Extensions (your-mahara-site/admin/extensions/plugins.php)

Answer (score 0):

Forum is enabled by default, notice that forum is a group feature. You need to create a group first, which will contain the general discussion forum by default, then within in the group on the forum tab you can add extra forums.

Mahara manual contains more information on forums: http://manual.mahara.org/en/1.6/groups/inside_group.html#forums